# Saving snapshot using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, automation, screenshot, clipboard, browser-automation

I am new to vbscript. I want to save a snapshot taken using vbscript of a internet explorer window opened by vbscript.

Code to load the page

```
Dim IE, stateString
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.toolbar = 1
ie.statusbar = 1
ie.width = 999
ie.height = 500
ie.left = 20
ie.theatermode = false
ie.theatermode = true
ie.theatermode = false
ie.top = 50
ie.navigate("file:///C:\Users\Vinit_Tiwari\Documents\vbscripts\someform.html")
'stateString = cstr(ie.readystate)
waitforload(ie)


ie.visible = 1

Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

wshShell.AppActivate "Some Form"
wshShell.SendKeys "% x"
```

Code to take snapshot

```
Dim oWordBasic
set oWordBasic = CreateObject("Word.Basic")
oWordBasic.sendkeys "{prtsc}"
oWordBasic.AppClose "Microsoft Word"
Set oWordBasic = Nothing
Wscript.Sleep 2000
```

Saving the snapshot

```
dim paint
set paint = wshShell.exec("mspaint")
do while paint.status = 0:loop
wshShell.appactivate("untitled-Paint")'this returns false
Wscript.sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "^v"
wscript.sleep 500
wshshell.sendkeys "^s"
wscript.sleep 500
wshshell.sendkeys "d:\test.png"
wscript.sleep 500
wshell.sendkeys "{Enter}"
Set wshshell = Nothing
```

Actually the previously opened ie window is having focus and the keystrokes are sent to the ie instead of paint. so is there any function which performs opposite work of `AppActivate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. Microsoft Word is in focus while the Print Screen button is pressed.  You can easily eliminate this problem by not using Microsoft Word at all.  It's not necessary.  The Print Screen function is a system hotkey and has nothing to do with Microsoft Word.  You should be using the Alt+PrintScreen combination which captures a screenshot of the currently focused window to the clipboard.

Second, if Paint is not in focus instead of IE, it's because you have the window title wrong. You are doing that part correctly.  AppActivate returns false if it cannot find a window with the specified title.  To be honest, Paint should alread have focus to begin with but it is good practice to make sure the window is activated first.

Also, is this a very old system?  Why are you using the Word.Basic automation object anyway out of curiosity?

Comment: Hi Nilpo, Thanks for your response... but could you please tell me what wiil be proper title to be passed in the `AppActivate` so that the application can be on foreground...

Comment: It's different for each version of Windows.  You'll need to open MS Paint and look at the title bar.

Comment: Actually i am using windows 7 and the title bar is showing 'Untitled-Paint' for mspaint and that's what i am trying.

Comment: There are usually space in between the words...  "Untitled - Paint"

Comment: Had the same problem, about the Word.Basic, i had to use this also because the Printscreen can not be used as a sendkey in Vbscript but it can in Word.Basic, it's the only reason i still use it

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Using `SendKeys "(%{1068})"` in VBScript works.